# Can not de-crypt files after upgrading to latest Ubuntu version

Tags: encryption

Encrypting files in an older version of Ubuntu with:

openssl des3 -e

Trying to decrypt files with:

openssl des3 -d

does not work in the newer Ubuntu version "18.04.1 LTS"

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use older version of encryption. Found this answer under "encryption":

use "-md md5" option in command line to force older encryption:

openssl des3 -md md5 -d